# Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, fatal-error

My CI version is CI2.3. I'm running [this php code](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Preparing-Database-P162.html) in my local host. I followed all the steps given there but I'm getting this error don't know why? and I changed Controller to CI_Controller. `Hello world Program` worked finely. This link code is not working. please need  help!

Comment: you can follow 1st what thay are given. May be you are new for CI. and study the rules http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: What 2.3 version? latest is 2.1.3 only. @Damien what man?

Comment: @KarSho I was referring to the CODE linked by OP, not to the MANUAL you linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should extend model like this in codeIgniter

```
class Modelname extends CI_Model
  {
   function __construct()
    {
          parent::__construct();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well actually the study guide is of old version of CI, where you used to extend your models from Model class as show in the guide. But now it has been changed. Now you have to extend it from CI_Model, same goes for Controller.

For controllers

```php
class Employee_controller extends CI_Controller
{
  //load the constructor
  function __construct()
  {
    //inherit the parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

and for models:

```php
class Employee_model extends CI_Model
{
  //load the constructor
  function __construct()
  {
    //inherit the parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a `model` in the model folder like `my_model.php`

And create the `class` like

```
class My_model extends CI_Model
{
   function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }
}
```

**Remember** the `class` and the `file` should be **same**.

Docs http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<?php

class Employee_model extends CI_Model
{
     //load the constructor
     function __construct()
     {
          //inherit the parent constructor
          parent::__construct();
     }
}
```